# How to upload multiple images in PHP...?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have "browse" button so i can select multiple images for upload, but let suppose i select 3 imgaes for upload and then again click on "browse" button for select another 2 images then last two imgaes uploading instead of all 5 images ( 2 new and 3 previous which i selected) so how can i solve this issue ? I want to upload current selected images and previous selected images together ?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<input type="file" data-max_length="1000" class="upload__inputfile" name="glow_nu_gallery[]" id="glow_nu_gallery" multiple />
```

PHP Code:

```
                $uploaddir         = wp_upload_dir();
                $raw_images        = $_FILES['glow_nu_gallery'];
                $upload_overrides = array( 'test_form' => false );
                $glow_p_photos = [];
                
                for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $raw_images['name'] ); $i++ ) {
                    $file       = $raw_images['name'][$i];
                    $uploadfile = $uploaddir['path'] . '/' . basename( $file );

                    move_uploaded_file( $raw_images["tmp_name"][$i] , $uploadfile );
                    $filename    = basename( $uploadfile );
                    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );

                    $attachment = array(
                        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
                        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
                        'post_content' => '',
                        'post_status' => 'inherit',
                        'menu_order' => 1000
                    );
                 }
```

Comment: The PHP in this question is irrelevant.